# How to override output (query) for views exposed filter?

Tags: views, 8

I have a views with exposed filter of taxonomy terms (select). It have multiple choice, and nodes output with that terms. But I want to change output of result of views for this filter. How can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to accomplish, some commonly used hooks are:

- [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/)
- [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/)
- [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/)
- There plenty of hooks to programmatically affect the results in the [Views API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/8.6.x)

Also there are plenty of [Views Plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/8.6.x) like the [Row Plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21row%21RowPluginBase.php/group/views_row_plugins/)